# On click of each word of textview text redirect to link

Tags: android

I want to redirect on different link on click of each word of textview text, as I search for this I found the solution, by which I got the click on each word of textview text and my first word redirect to link its working correctly but other words are not redirecting. Where am I going wrong?

My textview string is:

```
Disclamer | Privacy Policy | Terms of Use \u2022 All Rights Reserved &#169; company 2018.
```

Code:

```
  disclamer = findViewById(R.id.disclamerText);

    disclamer.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                mOffset = disclamer.getOffsetForPosition(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());
                //  mTxtOffset.setText("" + mOffset);
                if (findWordForRightHanded(disclamer.getText().toString(), mOffset).equalsIgnoreCase("Disclamer"))
                {
                    Intent viewIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
                                    Uri.parse("https://www.company.com/disclaimer.php"));
                    startActivity(viewIntent);
                }


                if (findWordForRightHanded(disclamer.getText().toString(), mOffset).equalsIgnoreCase("Privacy"))
                {
                    Intent viewIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
                            Uri.parse("https://www.company.com/privacy.php"));
                    startActivity(viewIntent);
                }

                if (findWordForRightHanded(disclamer.getText().toString(), mOffset).equalsIgnoreCase("Terms"))
                {
                    Intent viewIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
                            Uri.parse("https://www.company.com/terms-and-cond.php"));
                    startActivity(viewIntent);
                }
                if (findWordForRightHanded(disclamer.getText().toString(), mOffset).equalsIgnoreCase("company"))
                {
                    Intent viewIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
                            Uri.parse("https://www.company.com"));
                    startActivity(viewIntent);
                }

              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), findWordForRightHanded(disclamer.getText().toString(), mOffset), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Method

```
    private String findWordForRightHanded(String str, int offset) { // when you touch ' ', this method returns left word.
    if (str.length() == offset) {
        offset--; // without this code, you will get exception when touching end of the text
    }

    if (str.charAt(offset) == ' ') {
        offset--;
    }
    int startIndex = offset;
    int endIndex = offset;

    try {
        while (str.charAt(startIndex) != ' ' && str.charAt(startIndex) != '\n') {
            startIndex--;
        }
    } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        startIndex = 0;
    }

    try {
        while (str.charAt(endIndex) != ' ' && str.charAt(endIndex) != '\n') {
            endIndex++;
        }
    } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        endIndex = str.length();
    }

    // without this code, you will get 'here!' instead of 'here'
    // if you use only english, just check whether this is alphabet,
    // but 'I' use korean, so i use below algorithm to get clean word.
    char last = str.charAt(endIndex - 1);
    if (last == ',' || last == '.' ||
            last == '!' || last == '?' ||
            last == ':' || last == ';') {
        endIndex--;
    }

    return str.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to create seperate `TextView`s and define `onClickListener`s on them?

Comment: it written in to many activities and for that i need to change in xml and activity of each activity.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused. First of all, the x and y value you got from the motionEvent object are representing **X and Y screen coordinates of the touch** which are totally different from the offset expected as a parameter for the findWordForRightHanded function. Offset in the findWordForRightHanded is representing the **an index in the string text**.

So you can't pass the coordinates as from the motion event as offset without a mapping function, which will map each character offset in the string to its coordinates in the screen